# Bokeh Servers Autoreload

Tags: python, bokeh

Do Bokeh Servers have the capability to autoreload whenever changes are made to the source? Capability in a similar fashion to Django's autoreload in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0` this is not implemented. There is an open feature request issue you can subscribe to for updates: [`#4236` Implement --develop mode](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4236).

Answer (score 1):

Update [of this issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10977), use the flag --dev when invoking bokeh server